# Does pthread_create() always create one-to-one mapping between user and kernel thread?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

I would like to clarify user threads and kernel threads mapping in Linux on x86 architecture.

I couldn't think of the scenario that has many to one mapping between user and kernel threads when pthread library is used.

For example below code in user space creates 10 user threads using `pthread_create()`. My understanding is that each `pthread_create()` essentially calls system call `clone()` with flag `CLONE_THREAD`, which create a light weight process in kernel space. So in total there are 10 kernel processes/threads created in this case.

So the mapping between user threads and kernel threads is always one to one if pthread is used.

Am I right about this conclusion?

If so in case I want to create many-to-one or many-to-many mapping between user and kernel threads, what would be the proper APIs to use? Or is the mapping chosen by Kernel instead of controlled by users?

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pthread_create(xxx....).
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about the Linux implementation of pthreads called NPTL here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist  Thanks! So from the quote looks like it confirms my thought about pthread_create() ** Both of these are so-called 1:1 implementations, meaning that each thread maps to a kernel scheduling entity.  Both threading implemen‐tations employ the Linux clone(2) system call**,  so when do we need many-to-one or many-to-many mappping?  Does it solely depend on library used in user space?

Comment: Well, yes in theory it depends on the userland library; But in practice you don't need or want N:1 or N:M. The reason why those weren't chosen is that they have numerous complexities and consequences, and threads are relatively lightweight already. For example, how can the kernel deal with priority inversion if the mapping isn't 1:1? What happens if a thread does I/O? What if two threads disagree on CPU affinities? At some point working around all the problems is harder than just doing 1:1 and leaving the hard work to where it has to be done already (the kernel).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist thanks for the detailed answer. That solved my doubts!

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert, but I'm pretty sure that the thing called "kernel thread" in Linux has no direct relationship to user-mode programs. Kernel threads are threads that are created by the operating system for its own purposes. The threads that your program creates are just called "threads," and they can switch between executing non-priviliged code (e.g., the code that you wrote) and privileged code (e.g., system calls) as needed.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That is correct in that the term "kernel thread" is a *term of art* in the linux kernel. The kernel-side representation of a thread (schedulable entity) that OP refers to would be called a "task" in linux kernel lingo. However, outside this specific linux sphere, when generically discussing threading models, "kernel thread" commonly refers to the schedulable entity (the "1" in N:1, for example).